# How do I make LaTeX make things smaller, not add white space?

Tags: spacing

I am making a document with a lot of graphs. The general format is graph, explanation, graph, explanation, etc.

Because of this, `LaTeX` often moves graphs to the next page and this creates a lot of white space. I could manually use a resize box, but I want this process to be automatic in case I need to change the font size, margins, etc.

I would like to have `LaTeX` make the graphs smaller and remove some space between paragraphs, sections, subsections, etc. as necessary to fit as much as it can on one page. Is there anyway to do this without doing it manually for every graph?

Edit:

Notice how the first graph has a tremendous amount of white space. I would prefer `LaTeX` make both graphs smaller and have them on the same page. Is there a reliable way to have the graphs centered and accomplish this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{Test}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{-4em}{0em}
\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{0em}{0em}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0cm}{0em}{0em}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0cm}{0em}{0em}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0cm}{}

\newgeometry{margin=1in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Testing}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[domain=-10:10]{x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[domain=0:10]{x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE. If you should be using grapicx, \includegraphics has the options scale and width …

Comment: How you insert graphs? In `figure` floats? For eventual help you we need to see MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem

Comment: "moves graphs to the next page and this creates a lot of white space" That is why there are `figure`  environments.  This a so called  "float" because it can move away from the corresponding explanation to  avoid the gaps, but that is why the figures have  numbered captions that  can be labelled (`\label{foo}`)  and the referenced in  text with some like `see figure \ref{foo}`. Beside, use the `parskip` package to have  "flexible" paragraph spaces that will help to fit better text and figures.  But for God's sake, do not touch the spaces before/after sections.

Comment: if you are not using `figure` or equivalently using `[H]` on `figure` that is explicitly telling latex not to avoid bad white space, leaving it to you to do manual adjustments.